# PHP Window.location can't take query string

Tags: php, window, location, query-string

Hello all I am new to PHP

I am using window.location for redirecting to another PHP page.. but I need  to add some data to this

so that I am using

```
echo'<script> window.location="../post/view_full_post.php?ID=<? echo $ID ?>"</script> ';
```

but it not workes for me and gives me in my **URL**

```
http://bla bla/bla bla/post/view_full_post.php?ID=%3C?%20echo%20$ID%20?%3E
```

and says me that I am passing valid ID but it not working

Not Acceptable

```
An appropriate representation of the requested resource /bla bla/post/view_full_post.php could not be found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

so my question is how to pass query string into Window.location?

Comment: This is why I prefer to use the `sprintf()` function for this...

Answer (score 2):

Your below code is not correct:

```
echo'<script> window.location="../post/view_full_post.php?ID=<? echo $ID ?>"</script> ';
```

Replace it with the following:

```
echo '<script> window.location="../post/view_full_post.php?ID='.$ID.'"</script> ';
                                                             ^^^change here
```

Answer (score 2):

try changing it to

```
echo '<script> window.location="../post/view_full_post.php?ID=' . $ID . '"</script> ';
```

PHP doesn't evaluate code which appears in semi-quotes nor do you need to provide the echo in the middle of a line of code!

Answer (score 1):

Seeing as you are already in PHP, you don't need php opening and closing tags. I would recomend this:

```
echo "<script> window.location=\"../post/view_full_post.php?ID=$ID\"</script> ";
```

However, if you can, I would use this before any output is sent. It will be quicker.

```
header('Location: http://example.com');
```

Comment: If you do header('Location: http://www.example.com'); you may need ob_start(); at the top of the document.

Comment: @rsmith Why woudl you want to add all those escape chars to confuse the eye. See other 2 answers for the correct/elegant way of doing it.

Comment: @RiggsFolly so we can include the variable within the string?

Comment: @rsmith Also he is using PHP to code up some javascript to be run in the browser once that page is sent. What on earth would be the point of running a `header()` function in the PHP to throw another page? Read, Digest, Consider, ...... Answer.

Comment: @RiggsFolly "he is using PHP to code up some javascript to be run in the browser once that page is sent" Ahh yes, because there is so many legit reasons why one would want to do this and then redirect

Comment: @rsmith Ahhh, on closer examination, you have a valid point, well made! See I was right,  Read, Digest, Consider, ...... Answer. I must remember that!! I can only hope he cut out code to make the example simpler for use to view, and he actually does that based on some other condition that happens while the page is on view.